# C++11 Polymorphism : Call derived class method from base class pointer

Tags: c++11, pointers, polymorphism, overloading

In summary, I believe that the answer to my question is no. However, I will have hope and defer to those smarter than I.

I would like to call a class method of a derived class from the pointer to the base class. The inherited method(s) that are overloaded and desired to be called are pure virtual. I am able to get it to work in certain cases but not in one particular case, where the pure virtual method contains ellipsis placeholder for arguments.

The essence of what I desire is pasted below, any fixes and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
    #include <iostream>

    class A
    {
        public:
            virtual void setup()=0;
            virtual void callFunction(std::string str, ...)=0;
    };

    class B: public A
    {
        public:
            virtual void setup() {};        
            virtual void callFunction(std::string str, ...) { std::cout<<"\nB::callFunction("<<str<<")\n"; }; //compiles: not desired: a->callFunction("Hello World", 987); executes as B::callFunction
            //virtual void callFunction(std::string str, ...)=0; compile error: error: cannot declare variable 'c' to be of abstract type 'C'
    };

    class C: public B
    {
        public:
            void setup() { std::cout<<"\nC::setup\n"; };
            void callFunction(std::string str, int i) { std::cout<<"\nC::callFunction("<<str<<") = "<<i<<"\n"; };
    };

    int main()
    {          
        C c;
        A* a = (A*) new C;
        
        c.setup();
        c.callFunction("Hello World", 123);
        
        a->setup(); //WHY: does this pure virtual function still execute C::setup, this is desired for pure virtual method callFunction derived from class A
        a->callFunction("Hello World", 987);
        
        return 0;
        
    }
```

Comment: "I would like to call a class method of a derived class from the pointer to the base class." <-- Absolutely.  This is the very essence of dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: I love that a->setup() executes C::setup(). I do not desire that I'm only able to get a->callFunction("Hello") to execute B::callFunction(std::string). Does this clarify my problem vs. my intention?

Comment: @TonyA Ah, I see. The comment next to `a->setup();` did not convey it to me in that sense.

Comment: @TonyA Overloading and virtual function dispatch are orthogonal, you cannot overload a virtual function to influence virtual dispatch. You can only let `C` have a `callFunction(std::string str, ...)` implementation, which will be called then for all argument types and if necessary could forward its arguments to `B`'s implementation. However, I question the use of variadic functions in the first place. It is not type-safe and you need to somehow forward type information in the argument values (as e.g. `printf` does).

Comment: @user17732522, so I've updated the C::callFunction signature to match your comment. The question I have now is, how to access the thing in the ellipsis?

Comment: @TonyA See my (edited) comment. I would highly advice against ever using variadic functions. If you really must know, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic.

Comment: @user17732522, wonderful thanks.

Comment: I think this may help: https://godbolt.org/z/WY3az9jrf

Comment: @TonyA Before you go that route, just take all possible argument types `T` that your function is supposed to accept and declare individual overloads for them as pure virtual in `A`. Then you have overload resolution and virtual dispatch.

Comment: I forgot to use the keyword override on line 30 in that example.  The ellipsis can be tricky and will catch anything that is not a better fit ( I would generally advise against it )

Comment: @user17732522: I think I'm definitely going to try and stay away from ellipsis since it looks like either the va_list object to get data objects out is a homogenous type container and or it will require some less than ideal casts to different types.

Comment: @Jeff I think OP wants the `int` version to be called in `a->callFunction("Hello World", 987);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a conclusion from the comments:

You cannot influence virtual dispatch by overloading the virtual function in a derived class.

Overload resolution and virtual dispatch are orthogonal and the former happens before the latter.

So what you can do is declare multiple overloads, which are individually virtually dispatched.

In your case in the question this simply requires adding the `int` overload as a pure virtual to `A`:

```
class A
{
    public:
        virtual void setup()=0;
        virtual void callFunction(std::string, ...)=0;
        virtual void callFunction(std::string, int)=0;
};
```

To make sure that virtual function implementations are matched properly to these overloads, you should add the `override` specifier to all the implementations in the derived classes, e.g.:

```
void callFunction(std::string str, int i) override { std::cout<<"\nC::callFunction("<<str<<") = "<<i<<"\n"; };
```

If you need to support more argument types, simply add another pure virtual overload to `A` and implement it somewhere in the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: I've accepted the answer. However, I would note that I did already know about listing out each overload and was trying to be clever and subvert the need to edit the base class for each new overload. In the past I've successfully used, but not possible in my particular case, a base class of the following essence: template<typename ReturnT, typename... ArgsT>class Obj{ virtual ReturnT fcn(ArgsT...)=0; };

Comment: @TonyA Your question is kind of abstract without explaining the use case or its requirements. So it is hard to give any suggestion aside from "What you are trying to do doesn't work this way.". I had to guess here.

Comment: understandable. I typically drive for a minimal working example where I can either get a direct solution or interpolate/extrapolate from constructive criticism...In the past I remember having my hand slapped for not following the stack overflow guidelines. Nonetheless you have been helpful, thanks again.